# Manually set description of Pydantic model

Tags: pydantic

According to the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/), the description in the JSON schema of a Pydantic model is derived from the docstring:

```
class MainModel(BaseModel):
    """This is the description of the main model"""

    class Config:
        title = 'Main'


print(MainModel.schema_json(indent=2))
# {
#   "title": "Main",
#   "description": "This is the description of the main model",
#   ...
```

Is there a way to overwrite (resp. manually set) the value of the `"description"` entry (without the necessity to change the docstring), as it is for the `"title"`? Unfortunately, using an attribute `description` for the inner class `Config` does not work.

Comment: The documentation you provided in that link is now a 404. Would you be so kind to update it? I would really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the `schema_extra` attribute of the inner class `Config`:

```
class MainModel(BaseModel):
    """This is the description of the main model"""

    class Config:
        title = 'Main'
        schema_extra = {
            "description": "Main models are the models we use the most"
        }

print(MainModel.schema_json(indent=2))
# {
#   "title": "Main",
#   "description": "Main models are the models we use the most",
#   ...
```